# How to draw in buttons

Tags: html, css

How do I draw shapes within buttons? I am trying to draw a plus sign within a button.

```
.button{
  background-color: #423C3B;
  padding: 32px 32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

This is the code I have for my button.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to draw svg or what?

Comment: Use a  WebFont such as Fontawesome or glyphicons

Comment: Do you have an example of how you'd like it to look? Maybe some code you've attempted?

Answer (score 0):

For "drawing" simple, popular shapes,you can use fonts made for symbols, like font-awesome. Check this jsfiddle for an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/gc4z9o9n/

```
<button class="btn">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **only** need the plus sign an icon font could be overkill, requiring extra files and requests. You could just could use `+` or `&plus;` for your geometry.

```css
button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background-color: #423C3B;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">&plus;</button>
```

Adjust `padding`, `font-size` etc. as needed.

---

If you really liked the style of an icon font then I suggest using something like [IcoMoon App](https://icomoon.io/) to select **only the icons you need** to keep the footprint nice an minimal.